# nginx No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, nginx, same-origin-policy

I found that there is lot of such questions but I found no one making me solve my problem.

```
jQuery.post( 'http://example.com/api_offer/get_time_left', function(data) {

    console.log('get time');

}, 'json');
```

I am getting in chrome console this:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/api_offer/get_time_left. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '[my local domain]' is therefore not allowed access.

In the nginx site config there is set such settings:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
              fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
              fastcgi_index index.php;
              include fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

              add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

              proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;

        }
```

I am using Vagrant if that matters. But I get same error if I try to run this it unix server, not my localhost computer.

Tried looking at error logs of nginx and of and of this site domain but found nothing useful.

How can it not work if I have set * to allow any domain? What else can I do about this?

Comment: Please use the `example` domains to give examples, `domain.com` is a real site. You are making a request from `example.com` to `example.net`. Which site's nginx config are you editing?

Comment: Updated to example.com. Why do you think that I am making to example.net? I am editing nginx config of example.com

Comment: You have a webpage which is hosted somewhere ("my local domain"). You have an API, it is hosted somewhere else ("`example.com`"). Both sites have webservers. Which one of them are you editing the nginx config of?

Comment: Ok, I got now. I am editing the "hosted somewhere else site" config - which is example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was editing wrong part of config.

There were 2 server {} blocks.

One of them was for ssl on, and another was without ssl.

I was editing with ssl part

```
server {
    liten 443;
    ssl on;


    ....

}
```

But I was calling non ssl part of the site and it was not reacting.

The only question could be - how could I detect it sooner. I spent few hours on this.

So for future visitors who can have such problem - **check carefully, make sure you are editing the right block, or the right file of sites-enabled**

Comment: Why not run the whole thing under ssl and redirect and unencrypted traffic to it? The performance hit is not nearly what it used to be, and the security (and, in this case, simplicity) gains can be huge.

Comment: There was problem with C# program which is also a localhost server it would also then need ssl, otherwise page cannot make request to the C# program since page is secure, and C# localhost server is not secure. So thats why we needed both domains. Maybe it would be possible to make C# in localhost to be secure, but we are not C# programmers so we don't touch it. C# program is connected to cashier printers.